# Remove Azure SDK generated logs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights, azure-managed-identity

I have a .net Core 3.1 web app that connects to different Storage Accounts using Azure MSI.
The services are initialized using the Azure.Core.Extensions nuget package.

```
        var options = new BlobClientOptions
        {
            Diagnostics =
            {
                IsLoggingEnabled = false,
                IsTelemetryEnabled = false,
                IsDistributedTracingEnabled = false,
                IsLoggingContentEnabled = false
            },
            Retry =
            {
                MaxRetries = 3,
                Mode = RetryMode.Exponential,
                NetworkTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
                Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.7)
            }
        };
        builder.AddBlobServiceClient(StorageAccountConfigurator.GetStorageAccountUri(accountName))
                        .WithName(accountName)
                        .ConfigureOptions(options);
```

Everything works ok, but in Application Insights I get too many traces with this message:

```
ManagedIdentityCredential.GetToken succeeded. Scopes: [ https://storage.azure.com/.default ]
```

These are traces with Severity level:Information, **Category:Azure.Identity**.

Azure.Identity does not appear as a independent category in the documentation:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I have tried to create a ApplicationInsightsFilter (implements ITelemetryProcessor) to catch such traces and exclude them from logs, but somehow they overpass it (while debugging I was not able to catch such traces).

Is there an option to stop them from appearing in the logs?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-logging. Have you tried changing the log level for Azure.Identity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the log levels for `Azure.Identity` Package also in your `appsettings.json` file as specified in the [Logging Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-logging) and [Azure SDKs Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/logging) Microsoft docs.

For example:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Azure.Identity": "Information",
      "Azure.Core": "Debug"
    }
  }
}
```